# Matrix multiplication - single-dimension * multi-dimensional

Tags: java, matrix, multiplication

I need to multiply two matrices.  I understand pretty well how matrices work however in Java I am finding this a bit complex, so I researched a bit and found this.

```
    public static int[][] multiply(int a[][], int b[][]) {
    int aRows = a.length,
    aColumns = a[0].length,
    bRows = b.length,
    bColumns = b[0].length;
    int[][] resultant = new int[aRows][bColumns];

     for(int i = 0; i < aRows; i++) { // aRow
       for(int j = 0; j < bColumns; j++) { // bColumn
         for(int k = 0; k < aColumns; k++) { // aColumn
             resultant[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j];
          }
       } 
     }
     return resultant;
```

This code works fine. However the problem with this is that I need to multiply a single dimension matrix (1*5) by a multidimensional matrix (5*4), so the result will be (1*4) matrix and later on in the same program multiply a (1*4) matrix by a (4*3) matrix resulting in (1*3).

And I need to store the single dimension matrix in a normal array (double []) not multidimensional one!

I altered this code to the following but it still doesn't resolve the correct results.

```
    public static double[] multiplyMatrices(double[] A, double[][] B) {
    int xA = A.length;  
    int yB = B[0].length;       
    double[] C = new double[yB];

          for (int i = 0; i < yB; i++) { // bColumn
            for (int j = 0; j < xA; j++) { // aColumn
                C[i] += A[j] * B[j][i];
            }
    }
    return C;
```

Thanks in advance for any tips you may give :)

Comment: Keep in mind that your first solution has `O(n^3)` complexity. There are much more efficient methods to do matrix calculation.

Comment: @AdamArold You mean Strassen's algorithm? I can't say it's **much** more efficient than n^3

Comment: Well it only works for `n x n` if I remember right so it's ok.

Comment: Yes I am getting the meaning of the 3-level nested loop now.   It is very necessary.  (one to traverse the rows in A, the second to traverse the columns in B and the third to select the individual values for the sums.)

Comment: Can't see what is wrong. Can you produce some input and output expected? I've tried both algorithm and the actually do they give the same result, as expected.

Comment: Please see my test program and make there any change to show the problem. http://ideone.com/M3GGvH

Comment: @holap,  When i worked it out, I mean by hand, the second algorithm didnt give the required result.  The problem was that it did not have a 3 level nested loop, which is always required in java matrix multiplication (for reasons mentioned in previous comment).  Thanks

Comment: i dont understand why it worked wrong.    Maybe its because in the neural net things get more complicated, repeated for hundreds of times and a lot of decimal points.  its currently working, the outer-most loop is still only till 1 so, its more or less the same.

Comment: I don't understand either. As in the first loop will always iterate once there is no need to loop at all, as you just explained. It would be very useful having the input that reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RealMatrix](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html) to make it easier.

```
RealMatrix result = MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(a).multiply(MatrixUtils.createRealMatrix(b));
double[] array = result.getRow(0);
```